# Rename files to the inode

Tags: files, scripting, pipe, rename, mv

I'm trying to rename files in a directory based on the inode number. That seems to be the unique number that will keep the files (pictures) in the order in which they were taken. I want to do this as a complete directory vs individual files.

`ls -i` gives me the inode number for all files, but I need to pipe data that to rename or mv for all files.

Current Output: `ls -li`

```
46923838 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6937237 Jan 24 15:26 DSC_1167.JPG

46923839 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6692804 Jan 24 15:26 DSC_1168.JPG

46923840 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6735745 Jan 24 15:26 DSC_1169.JPG

46923841 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 7709324 Jan 24 15:26 DSC_1170.JPG

46923842 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 7645673 Jan 24 15:26 DSC_1171.JPG
```

Desired Results:

```
46923838 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6937237 Jan 24 15:26 46923838.JPG

46923839 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6692804 Jan 24 15:26 46923839.JPG

46923840 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 6735745 Jan 24 15:26 46923840.JPG

46923841 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 7709324 Jan 24 15:26 46923841.JPG

46923842 -rw-r--r-- 1 me me 7645673 Jan 24 15:26 46923842.JPG
```

Update: I need to take the "exif:DateTimeOriginal:" and send it as the new name of the file.

desktop 2016-10-22 # identify -verbose DSC_1140.JPG | grep 
exif:DateTimeOriginal:
    exif:DateTimeOriginal: 2016:10:22 16:29:33

desktop 2016-10-22 # identify -verbose DSC_1140.JPG | grep filename:
filename: DSC_1140.JPG

Comment: There is nothing to suggest that the inode numbers will be allocated in the order that the pictures are taken.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I see the error in my thinking. How can I get the data from the Properties>Image>Date Taken field? "stat" for the pictures is telling me it has no birth date.

Date Taken: 2016:10:12 11:13:26

me@desktop ~/2016-10-22 $ stat Pic_160
File: ‘Pic_160’
Size: 6924612 Blocks: 13528 IO Block: 4096 regular file
Device: 801h/2049d Inode: 44171294    Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/      me)   Gid: ( 1000/      me)
Access: 2017-01-25 23:16:44.764049619 -0500
Modify: 2017-01-24 15:15:38.922054000 -0500
Change: 2017-01-25 23:16:24.944048721 -0500
Birth:

Comment: See also `exiftool -d '%FT%T.jpg' '-Filename<DateTimeOriginal' ./*.JPG` to rename them based on the time the picture was taken as stored in the EXIF tags.

Comment: Thanks  Stéphane Chazelas ! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry to anyone for updating/changing the question. Just showing the "progress" I was making.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from hardlink(s), inode of a file is guaranteed to be unique, within the same filesystem. Iterating over the `.JPG` files in the current directory, and renaming (`mv`-ing) with help from `stat` to get the inode:

```
for i in *.JPG; do echo mv -- "$i" "$(stat -c '%i' "$i")"; done
```

`echo` will spit out the `mv` command that would be run. Remove `echo` for actual action:

```
for i in *.JPG; do mv -- "$i" "$(stat -c '%i' "$i")"; done
```

---

Also, if you want the final filenames to have the `.JPG` extension too:

```
for i in *.JPG; do mv -- "$i" "$(stat -c '%i' "$i").JPG"; done
```

Comment: Guaranteed to be unique, but *not* guaranteed to not also be in use as a filename.  Just as a point.

Comment: _Guaranteed to be unique_ except for hard links (in effect two hard links are the same files but they are different directory entries pointing to it. Above, you'd end up renaming all of them to the same file. Not really losing data though).